# TypeError on "drush config-export"

Tags: 8, drush, configuration

I've been receiving the following error message when trying to do a `drush config-export` command.
However, I am able to successfully do the configuration export from the Drupal admin page (`admin/config/development/configuration/full/export`).

```
TypeError: Argument 2 passed to [error] Drupal\Core\Config\FileStorage::write() must be of the type array, boolean given, called in /vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/config.drush.inc on line 519 in Drupal\Core\Config\FileStorage->write() (line 140 of /web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/FileStorage.php)
#0
/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/config.drush.inc(519): Drupal\Core\Config\FileStorage->write('field.field.nod...', false)
#1
/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/config.drush.inc(448): _drush_config_export('sync', '../data/sync', false)
#2
/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(422): drush_config_export()
#3
/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#4
/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(199): drush_command()
#5
/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch(Array)
#6
/vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot-bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#7 /Users/Bcorrigan/sites/flowrite8/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(12):
drush_main()
#8
{main}.
```

The only reference I can find to something similar is here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2830047

But I did not have that module installed when I started getting the error. It's installed now, but still getting the error and will probably remove it soon.

I started receiving the error yesterday, reverting to previous version of Git have made no difference in receiving the error.

Anyone else run into this? Know how to fix? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: me too. started using drupalconsole to export as I didn't have time to look into this. but definitely the same and consistent issue.


 Drush Version   :  8.1.9 
 Drupal version   :  8.2.5

Comment: The behavior can happen if the configuration directory (in your case `../data/sync'`) is not readable/writable by the webserver. Are you sure you can read/write with your webserver in this folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
drush config-export --destination="<folder-path>"
```

Path should be some writable folder

Answer (score 0):

This issue can happen if the export directory does not have the write permissions.
I just created a folder with write permissions and I was able to successfully export the configurations using `drush config-export`. Or, if you want to choose different directory just specify --destination params as

```bash
drush config-export --destination="YOUR_FOLDER_PATH"
```